# powershell how to loop over files and zip them

Tags: powershell

First time powershell development - have to say not intuitive for a linux scripter.

need to loop over files to zip them and getting errors - anyone have some feedback on a good one liner?

```
gci C:\temp -r *.csv | 
Where-Object { $_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-10)} | 
ForEach-Object {'c:\temp\bin\gzip.exe' $_.FullName}
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, what errors are you getting ?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the call (&) operator to actually execute the command in the string. If you don't do this, the string is printed out as the result of an expression evaluation (instead of as a command.)

```
gci C:\temp -r *.csv `
    | Where-Object { ... } `
    | ForEach-Object { & 'c:\temp\bin\gzip.exe' $_.FullName}
```

Incidentally, if you install the PowerShell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com) then this becomes much simpler:

```
   ls c:\temp -r *.csv `
       | where { ... }
       | write-gzip
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well as a one liner I can run on the fly from powershell. Not quite as intuitive as a find | xargs  - but it got the job done..

Answer (score 2):

Applications can be executed in Powershell just by giving their name / path, you don't have to enclose them in quotes as strings and then use `iex` or `&`:

```
c:\temp\bin\gzip.exe $_.FullName
```

would work for the zipping part.

Comment: if the path to the utility contains spaces, then you do need the quotes.

Comment: @x0n - Valid point, though I was concentrating on case in hand.

Answer (score 1):

The following version of your script could come in handy when you can't rely on external tools:

```
gci C:\temp -recurse *.csv | 
Where-Object { $_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-10)} | 
ForEach-Object {
  $zip =  $_.fullname -replace "\.csv",".zip"; 
  new-item -type File $zip -force;
  ((new-object -com shell.application).namespace($zip)).copyhere($_.fullname)
}
```